# Result table more retain single array how can

Tags: c#, datatable

Hi sp returns 2 tables set record how to marge result set.

Result set table 1:

[image]

Result set table 2:

[image]

Comment: Do you want in C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dtAll = new DataTable();
...
dtAll.Merge(dtOne);
dtAll.Merge(dtTwo);
dtAll.Merge(dtThree);
...
```

and so on.

This technique is useful in a loop where you want to iteratively merge data tables:

```
DataTable dtAllCountries = new DataTable();

foreach(String strCountry in listCountries)
{
    DataTable dtCountry = getData(strCountry); //Some function that returns a data table
    dtAllCountries.Merge(dtCountry);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If iam understanding you correctly
You wish to merge 2 identical data tables

```
dataTable.Merge(dataTable1);
```